# What's the best build for a Ranger in Baldur's Gate 1 EE?

Tags: xbox-one, baldurs-gate-enhanced

I just got The Enhanced Edition of Baldur's Gate on XBOX and I've been meaning to roll a Ranger. However I've never played one before and I wanna know what is the best type of build for one. I'm primarily thinking about staying at range unless the situation absolutely calls for me to get into melee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay at range, the Archer kit is what you're looking for. It trades melee proficiency (leaving you merely competent) for ranged abilities.

Pick Elf as your race for the extra dexterity.

When assigning your stats, dexterity is the most important. Constitution is also useful for the extra hp. Besides that you want a decent strength and ideally 9+ intelligence for literacy. Wisdom can't be below 13 which is more than you need and charisma is useless.

Put weapon proficiency into shortbow, longbow, or crossbow. If you plan on planying through the trilogy, shortbow is the best as the Gesen Bow is the only bow with +4 arrows. The extra 2 points at first level can go into your melee weapon of choice and either single-weapon (for the AC) or the third point of dual-wielding (for two scimitars).